# Is it possible to send messages outside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm writing a discord.py script and I wanted to make alerts for my original code but I'm not sure how to write it properly:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Client is ready.')

    channel = client.get_channel(00000000000000)
    await channel.send(f'example')
```

this works fine but when I write this outside it doesn't want to work. Is there any way writing this section?

```
channel = client.get_channel(000000000000000)
await channel.send(f'message')
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything has to be async so it has to be in a function

```py
async def sendmsg():
    channel = client.get_channel(000000000000000)
    await channel.send(f'message')
```

Then you can do `await sendmsg()` in the on_ready or another async function.

Answer (score 0):

The code outside the functions is getting called when you start the file. So as the bot isn't ready there, you can't say it to get a channel and send a message to it.

So you have to put the `channel = ... await channel.send` in another function, you call when a specific thing happens.

Also as FluxedScript said, you have to put it into an async function, because it has an `await` in it and then you have to call it with `await FUNCTION_NAME`.